# Using PipelineModel.load() in custom MLFlow PyFunc class results in error

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, apache-spark-mllib, mlflow, feature-store

Am creating a custom PyFunc class to use with Databricks Feature Store as their Model Serving UI and feature store's log_model() methods only work with the PythonModel class.

The underlying model is a PipelineModel() which perform various binning and transformations prior to the model.

The function is as such:

```
import mlflow.pyfunc
from pyspark.ml.functions import vector_to_array
from pyspark.ml import PipelineModel
    class custom_model_class(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    
      def __init__(self, model_path, threshold):
        self.model_path = model_path
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.model = None
    
      def load_context(self, context):
        self.model = PipelineModel.load(self.model_path)
    
      def predict(self, context, model_input):
        return self.model.transform(model_input).withColumn("prediction_opt_thresh", when(vector_to_array("probability")[1] > lit(self.threshold), 1).otherwise(0))
    
    custom_model = custom_model_class(model_path = pipeline_model_directory, threshold = 0.52)
```

However I am getting this error:

```
'RuntimeError: SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.', from <command-2164064949918430>, line 12.
```

I have tried various other methods to solve the issue, but most of them give the same issue:

1. Either JVM returns None, indicating there is no Spark Session
2. Creating a Spark Session returns the above error
3. Using a mlflow.pyfunc.load_model (which does not utilize the Spark session) to load the PipelineModel() object works but does not return probabilities.

How do I resolve this? Is there a way for Feature Store and MLLib to work together?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. The issue lay in the way that we were using Feature Store's log_model() function. See the documentation here https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/python/latest/feature-store/client.html

You have to specify an argument 'flavor' in this method. If you specify anything that doesn't happen to be mlflow.spark (but still within the list of [approved flavours](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#model-api)), the environment you run the model with using the score_batch() function will in fact not have the result.

fs.log_model(
model,
"model",
flavor=mlflow.pyfunc,
training_set=training_set,
registered_model_name="example_model"
)

To ensure you are running in the correct type of environment, you need a spark context, and the flavor has to be mlflow.spark.

Hope this helps anyone using the new Feature Store API.